# electronjs app shows empty white screen sometimes after running

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am using electron forge with typescript integration.

My app works fine and is fully functional without any errors in console.

also I do (after mainWindow creation)

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
```

after I do

```
npm start
```

and the electron's main window sometimes, randomly shows only an empty white screen without the html page and without devtools either! like it's crashed or something.

also if I choose to not open dev tools from the beginning then I can't open them from the file menu or shortcut. I can't reopen them either if I close them once.

my **index.ts** full code is:

```js
import {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} from 'electron';

import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'


// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup'))
{ // eslint-disable-line global-require
    app.quit();
}

var mainWindow:any
const createWindow = (): void => {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,

        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'));

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {

});
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
    {
        app.quit();
    }
});
app.on('activate', () => {
        // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
        {
            createWindow();
        }
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-new-app",
  "productName": "my-new-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Alex",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "my_new_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "@types/codemirror": "^5.60.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
    "electron": "13.1.3",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "codemirror": "^5.62.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.6.0",
    "json-string-formatter": "^1.0.1",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

I get these warnings always

> Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
> Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
> this app to unnecessary security risks.
> For more information and help, consult
> https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
> This warning will not show up
> once the app is packaged.
> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for file:///D:/myapp/src/preload.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input

btw `preloader.js` and `.map` is at `app/dist` not in `app/src`. in `app/src` there is the `preloader.ts` (typescript) file

Comment: do you mind sharing the contents of your `package.json`?

Comment: @khuynh I just did thanks!

Comment: What's the console output when you run the app?

Comment: > tsc && electron-forge start

√ Checking your system
√ Locating Application
√ Preparing native dependencies
√ Launching Application

Comment: btw preloader.js and .map is at app/dist not in app/src. in app/src there is the preloader.ts (typescript) file

Comment: [this bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27353)?

Comment: @pokemon did you find the root cause and solution?